# Перегрузка операций

Tags: c++

Почему некоторые символы операций можно переопределить с помощью обычных функций (например, "+"), а некоторые только методами классов (например, "=")?

Comment: Можно примеры приведённых переопределений? Как Вы переопределите + обычной функцией?

Comment: Ну тот же = должен обязательно слева иметь ссылку на объект. И это автоматически обеспечивается, если он член класса. А если нет - можно огрести неприятностей... Да, с точки зрения терминологии - не "обычных", а "свободный", не являющийся членом класса.

Comment: думаю, что правильный ответ на этот вопрос - так сложилось исторически. Но истинная причина видимо в том, что свободную функцию можно определить в другом месте и тем самым поменяв функционал класса. И если поменять оператор присваивания, то это может быть очень и очень неприятно.